# Jaccard index, matrix notation

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix with rows representing events and columns representing users. The elements of the matrix are binary values indicating if a user has attended the event or not.

\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&1&1\\1&1&0&0&1\\ 1&0&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}

I need matrix notation to compute the [Jaccard distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) between users.

\begin{align}
  J(U_1,U_2)=\frac{|U_1\cap U_2|}{|U_1\cup U_2|}
\end{align}

To compute the numerator I can use the matrix operation 
\begin{align}
  A^T\times A
\end{align}

Now my question is how to get the denominator of Jaccard index using the matrix notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the all-ones matrix $N,$ with the same dimensions as $A,$ to define the symmetric matrix
$$\eqalign{
L &= A^TN + N^TA \\
}$$
Then the Jaccard matrix can be written as
$$\eqalign{
J &= (A^TA)\oslash(L-A^TA) \\
}$$
where $\oslash$ denotes elementwise (aka Hadamard) division.

The elements of this $J$-matrix are the Jaccard distances, i.e.
$$J_{ik} = J(U_i,U_k)\\$$

---

**NB:**  $\;$The third column of your $A$-matrix is problematic 
and results in $J_{33}=\frac{0}{0}$

One way to address this is to use the elementwise pseudoinverse
$$
\big(M^\oplus\big)_{ij}
 = \big(M_{ij}\big)^+
 = \begin{cases}
  M_{ij}^{-1}\;&{\rm if\;}|M_{ij}|\ge\varepsilon\\0\;&{\rm otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
Then the expression for the $J$-matrix becomes
$$J = (A^TA)\odot(L-A^TA)^\oplus$$
where $\odot$ denotes the elementwise (aka Hadamard) product.

Comment: Being working on Jaccard index (see my recent question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3173596), I just saw this rather old question and your rather recent answer. I propose a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to compute the number of elements of all *unions* which is based on the De Morgan duality relationship :

$$S_i \cup S_j=(S_i^c \cap S_j^c)^c \tag{1}$$

(where $^c$ means "complementary set").

Let us keep the same name $A$ for the initial matrix.

We have first to constitute the matrix $B$ of complementary sets. This is simply done by replacing each entry $A_{ij}$ by $1-A_{ij}$. The corresponding matrix operation is $B=U-A$ where $U$ is a matrix of ones with the convenient size.

The second operation in (1) (taking the intersection of complementary sets) is done evidently by matrix operation $C=B^TB$.

Let us introduce notation $|.|$ for the number of elements of a set.

The generic entry $C_{ij}$ of $C$ is

$$C_{ij}=|S_i^c \cap S_j^c|$$

Thus

$$e-C_{ij}=|(S_i^c \cup S_j^c)\color{red}{^c}|\tag{2}$$

(where $e$ is the number of "events").

The matrix operation corresponding to (2) is $Q=eU-C$ where $U$ is again a matrix of ones with the convenient dimensions, reaching thus our objective.

---

Here is a Matlab program which does the work :

```
u=5;% number of users; ( = number of sets)
e=3;% number of events ( = number of elements)
A=[1 1 0 1 1
   1 1 0 0 1
   1 0 1 1 1];% data matrix (dimensions e x u)
P=A'*A; % P_{ij}=|S_i inter S_j|  
B=ones(e,u)-A;
C=B'*B;
Q=e*ones(u,u)-C ; % Q_{ij}=|S_i union S_j|
Jac=P./Q, % matrix of Jaccard indices
```

Comment: An equivalent shorter program might eliminate the variables (C,Q) and re-define (B), i.e. 
$${\mathrm{
 B = A' * ones(e,u); \\
 Jac = P \, ./ \, (B+B'-P); 
}}$$

Comment: I chose to use these "temporary" variables for didactic purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive remarks and +1 for your update part.