# proof of triangle inequality of |△| / (||+||) ≤ |△ |/ (||+||) + |△| / (||+||)

Tags: inequality, triangle-inequality

I'm trying to prove this triangle inequality where $A \triangle B = A \cup B - A \cap B$
$$
\frac{|A \triangle B|}{|A| + |B|} \leq \frac{|A \triangle C|}{|A| + |C|} + \frac{|B \triangle C|}{|B| + |C|}
$$

I came up with this and it doesn't work.
$$
\frac{|A \triangle C|}{|A| + |C|} + \frac{|B \triangle C|}{|B| + |C|} \geq \frac{|A \triangle C| + |B \triangle C|}{|A \cap B| + |C|} \geq \frac{|A \triangle C \cup B \triangle C|}{|A \cap B| + |C|}
$$

Any help would be appreaciated.

I just found it doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality, for example when A={0}, B={1}, C={0, 1}, 1 > 1/3 + 1/3. This post can be closed.

Comment: How is defined $\frac{X}{Y}$ among sets?

Comment: @Raffaele: I guess that is set difference and $\le$ might be subset relation. But I donot have a guess for "+".

Comment: @Bumblebee I knew that. It's the "fraction" that is unclear

Comment: @Raffaele: Agree with you. OP should carefully introduce his notations.

Comment: Maybe $\frac{A}{B}:=\frac{|A|}{|B|}$ where $|S|$ is the cardinal (number of elements) of finite set $S$...

Comment: Is $A+B:=|A|+|B|$  ?

Comment: sorry just got back. @JeanMarie you are right. $\frac{X}{Y}$ is the number of items in X divided by the number of items in Y. I will correct my notations.

Comment: @JeanMarie |△| / ||+|| = (1 + 1) / (1 + 1) = 1

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I erase my wrong calculation... Personally, I had been working on this kind of "pseudo-distances" linked to "Jaccard index". See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2119199. You will find there as well a reference to a question of mine.

Comment: Thank you @JeanMarie, speaking of Jaccard index like metrics,  do you happen to know any similar metrics which will have different distances even when 2 sets are not overlapping? For example, the Jaccard index of 2 non-overlapping spans are always 0, so it cannot measure how far apart the 2 spans are, i.e. {0, 1, 2} and {3,4} are as bad as {0, 1, 2} and {99,100}.

Comment: As I understand it, what you are looking for would be a "mixture" of 2 "metrics", one purely based on sets and another one inherited from the usual distance on $\mathbb{N}$ for example. Have you heard about [**Hausdorff distance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance)? it is a very effective distance between sets in a metric space.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, I tried the Hausdorff distance which is the gap between 2 spans in the span metric space. I also tried to use a distance on the length of the spans, i.e. ||A| - |B||, however their scales are much larger than the Jaccard distance. I have to normalise them first.  Are there any conventional ways to standardise these distances?

Comment: There are different "standardisations" of distances, like the ones you can see in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2863127)

Comment: Having a distance $\le 1$ has some merits, in particular "psychological" (scale $0-100 \%$) and/or with connection with probabilities' range.